# CouchDB cartridge

Tags: couchdb, openshift

I tried the [CouchDB cartrige](https://github.com/marianoguerra/couchdb-for-openshift) from github but it throws this error:

```
remote: make[5]: Leaving directory `/var/lib/openshift/534031044382ec3eee123057/app-root/runtime/couchdb/otp_src_R15B03/lib/inets/src/ftp'
remote: make[4]: Leaving directory `/var/lib/openshift/534031044382ec3eee123057/app-root/runtime/couchdb/otp_src_R15B03/lib/inets/src/ftp'
remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: -1)
remote: Error message: Shell command '/var/lib/openshift/534031044382ec3eee123057/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/action_hooks/build' exceeded timeout of 3398
remote: 
remote: For more details about the problem, try running the command again with the '--trace' option.
To ssh://534031044382ec3eee123057@couchapp-mycompany.rhcloud.com/~/git/couchapp.git/
   bf04d23..eee84a7  master -> master
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a community supported cartridge, try logging an issue with the cartridge maintainer on that github repository.